# Facebook select friends and post UIDs to custom URL

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm building a facebook connect application, and here's the specific use case I'm trying to solve (using the Facebook Connect Javascript toolkit - http://github.com/facebook/connect-js)

1. There is a link on a page that a user clicks to "invite friends".
2. This click opens up a facebook friend selector widget (something like the multi-friend-selector), and the user selects friends from it.
3. The selected friends are POST-ed to a custom URL using an Ajax call and the selector widget goes away.

I'm able to do steps 1 and 2 using a fb:request-form and fb:multi-friend-selector. However, by default that posts to facebook and redirects the page. Is there a way to simply retrieve the UIDs of the selected users and then post them to a custom URL instead?

Answer (score 0):

This topic is [muddy water right now](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Invites).

The current way is to implement your custom URL with an [fb:req-choice](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:req-choice) in the `content` attribute of your `fb:request-form` as described [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Integrating_an_Invite_Form_into_Your_Website).

But as you can clearly see on that page - they are soon deprecating that element and changing how requests/invites work in general.  So you can implement it like this for now, but will probably have to change it when they release more details about the new system.